# How to add a help command to a .exe program?

Tags: python, cmd, exe

I just finished writing a code in Python and converted it into a .exe file, and as a add-on I want to add a `help` command to show on a command prompt a quick explanation of what my program does. Do I have to add the parameter in my .py file or do I need to create a .ini/.bat file for this parameter?

What I want to happen: In the path of my .exe directory on CMD, type a `help` command to show a text of what my program does.

Comment: I'd say something like `myprogr.exe /?` or `myprog --help` would make a whole lot more sense rather than trying to override (or somehow reuse) the native help.exe if you happen to run it from the desired path. Running `myprog.exe` without any parameters could default to  `myprog.exe /?` if need be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raya's answer is good, but the code can be even shorter. You don't need to add a specific help option to the parser. This will be added by default if you initialise the parser with a description argument, e.g.,

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My code does great stuff")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then running

```
myprogram.exe --help
```

will give:

```
My code does great stuff

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```